# How can I know if my flash storage is usb 1.1 or 2.0

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive

Fedora 14
    HP Netbook 210 Mini

My netbook book is new 3 weeks, so should support 2.0.

I have just bought a new flash drive 4GB. It seems very slow when copying data.

I have done the following using lsusb:

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0007 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0314 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 090c:1000 Feiya Technology Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But doesn't give me any details of my actual flash drive that I have bought.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Your output tells you that the device is plugged in to a 2.0 hub.  Check dmesg to see what driver it loads as noted in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system I get:

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0781:5530 SanDisk Corp.   
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 090c:c371 Feiya Technology Corp.   
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This tells me that SanDisk device is on a 2.0 port by matching bus numbers

right after the device is connected and powered up...
dmesg | tail -n 20 gives me this:

```
[91212.433178] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off  
[91212.433183] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00  
[91212.433186] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through  
[91212.435812] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through  
[91212.435819]  sdb: sdb1  
[91212.445572] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through  
[91212.445577] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk  
[91337.279149] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, address 6  
[91435.428546] usb 2-7: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 7  
[91435.562159] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-7:1.0  
[91436.560919] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer           1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2  
[91436.561956] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0  
[91436.563973] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 15625216 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 GB/7.45 GiB)  
[91436.566984] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off  
[91436.566991] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00  
[91436.566996] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through  
[91436.570387] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through  
[91436.570396]  sdb: sdb1  
[91436.580519] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through  
[91436.580525] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Telling me here: `[91435.428546] usb 2-7: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 7` that it's a 2.0 device

you also may find lsusb more succinct than lspci

Comment: A low-speed device would be handled by either ohci_hcd or uhci_hcd.

Answer (score 1):

Try `lsusb -v` and look at the `bcdUSB` field, that gives you the highest compatible USB version the device speaks:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0781:5530 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer U3 4gb SDCZ36
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0781 SanDisk Corp.
  idProduct          0x5530 Cruzer U3 4gb SDCZ36
```

This is an older example for a USB stick I have here, a newer external hard drive said:

```
  bcdUSB               2.10
```

So both work fine with USB 2.0, whereas a flatbed scanner does only 1.1:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 04a9:2220 Canon, Inc. CanoScan LIDE 25
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol       255
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x04a9 Canon, Inc.
  idProduct          0x2220 CanoScan LIDE 25
```

Of course aking1012's answer should also do the trick of telling you to which USB bus (ehci or not) the device id connected.